# Acorn - why arrow function throws parsing error?

Tags: javascript, acorn

I'm trying to parse old React component source code with Acorn.

Component to parse (ProjectNew2.js):

```
import React from 'react';

class ProjectNew extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount = () => {
        // do some stuff here...
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>fooo</div>
        );
    }

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProjectNew);
```

any my JavaScript code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const Fs = require('fs')
const acorn = require("acorn")
const jsx = require("acorn-jsx")

let fileName = "./ProjectNew2.js";
let cnt = Fs.readFileSync(fileName).toString()

let s = acorn.Parser.extend(jsx()).parse(cnt, {ecmaVersion: "latest", sourceType: "module"});

console.log(s)
```

and exception:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token (21:22)

**Question: why Acorn throws an exception while parses arrow function?**

When I change parse to:

```
componentDidMount(){
    // do some stuff here...
}
```

Acorn parses it successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem you are having is that class fields are a [stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) before the TC 39 and not yet part of the Javascript language (even if browsers already support them). Much like with JSX you will probably need the [appropriate parser plugin](https://github.com/acornjs/acorn-class-fields) to parse them. This almost certainly has nothing to do with arrow functions, you could likely write `class Foo { x = 'x' }` and get the same error.

Comment: You are true, "acorn-class-fields" plugins solve it.